# The largest aligned rectangular with fixed aspect ratio in an arbitrary convex polygon?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, convex-optimization

How to calculate the width / height of the largest **aligned** rectangular with **fixed aspect ratio** in an arbitrary **convex polygon**?

The examples of such rectangles (red) in the different convex polygons (black) are presented on this image:

[image: are presented on this image].

I found different papers on subject, but they are not fit to set of my limitations. That's weird, because they should significally simplify the algorithm, but unfortunately I didn't found any clue of it.

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can solve for a square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed ratio does simplify the problem since now there's a linear program.

You want to find x1, y1, x2, y2 to maximize x2 − x1 subject to the constraints that (x2 − x1) h = w (y2 − y1) where the aspect ratio is w:h, and for each linear inequality defining the convex polygon, each of the points (x1, y1), (x1, y2), (x2, y1), (x2, y2) satisfy it.

For example, consider this convex polygon: [image: Polygon]

The linear program for the rectangle with four points *(x_1, y_1)*, *(x_1, y_2)*, *(x_2, y_2)*, *(x_2, y_1)*, aspect ratio *r = w / h* and inscribed to the polygon above will be following:

[image: Linear program]

In theory, there are specialized algorithms for low-dimensional linear programming that run in linear time. In practice, you can throw a solver at it. If you want to code your own, then you could do the simplex method, but gradient descent is even simpler.

First let's get rid of the equality constraint and a variable by maximizing z over variables x, y, z subject to the point-in-polygon constraints for x1 = (x − w z), y1 = (y − h z), x2 = (x + w z), y2 = (y + h z). Second let's trade in those constraints for an objective term. Normally a point-in-polygon constraint will look like (signed distance to half-plane) ≤ 0. Instead we're going to apply a penalty term to the objective. Let α > 0 be a parameter. The new term is −exp(α (signed distance to half plane)). If the signed distance is negative (the point is inside half-plane), then the penalty will go to zero as α goes to infinity. If the signed distance is positive, then the penalty goes to minus infinity. If we make α large enough, then the optimal solution of the transformed problem will be approximately feasible.

This is what it looks like in Python. I'm not a continuous optimization expert, so caveat emptor.

```py
# Aspect ratio.
w = 3
h = 2

# Represented as intersection of half-spaces a*x + b*y - c <= 0 given below as
# (a, b, c). For robustness, these should be scaled so that a**2 + b**2 == 1,
# but it's not strictly necessary.
polygon = [(1, 1, 20), (1, -2, 30), (-2, 1, 40)]

# Initial solution -- take the centroid of three hull points. Cheat by just
# using (0, 0) here.
x, y, z = (0, 0, 0)

from math import exp

# Play with these.
alpha = 10
rate = 0.02

for epoch in range(5):
    for iteration in range(10 ** epoch, 10 ** (epoch + 1)):
        # Compute the gradient of the objective function. Absent penalties, we
        # only care about how big the rectangle is, not where.
        dx, dy, dz = (0, 0, 1)
        # Loop through the polygon boundaries, applying penalties.
        for a, b, c in polygon:
            for u in [-w, w]:
                for v in [-h, h]:
                    term = -exp(alpha * (a * (x + u * z) + b * (y + v * z) - c))
                    dx += alpha * a * term
                    dy += alpha * b * term
                    dz += alpha * (a * u + b * v) * term
        x += rate * dx
        y += rate * dy
        z += rate * dz
    print(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've tested your approach on several examples and it works pretty well. It found not only width/height of the largest rectangle, it found also the coordinates of such rectangle.

Comment: The only one thing bothers me: I should add  the large amount code for simplex algorithm implementation in my tiny program, so I'm going to try also the @Yves Daoust solution to compare them later.

Comment: @grom if this code isn't performance sensitive, you could also do gradient descent. I'll post a sample later.

Comment: @grom added code. If you're going to homebrew gradient descent in production, you should probably look up the right way to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Don't you mind to extend your answer and add my example of the linear program for a convex polygon (https://pastebin.com/mrfxfEZA)? Change it as you like, the crucial part is my images. I assume it may be useful for readers of this question in the future.

Comment: Sorry for delaying the answer accepting. I still need to test Yves's solution, but my knowledge in computational geometry make the progress extremely slow.

Comment: @grom you got it.

Comment: @grom come to think of it, Seidel's randomized linear programming algorithm is quite simple (until you try to handle degenerate cases, at least).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

WLOG the rectangle can be a square (stretch space if necessary).

Then the solution is given by the highest point of the distance map to the polygon, in the Chebyshev metric (L∞). It can be determined from the medial axis transform, itself obtained from the Voronoi diagram.

Comment: I'm going to try your approach. Thanks.

Comment: @grom: beware that the metric is non-standard.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm stuck. I still need to dig deeper to understand how to build Voronoi diagram for Chebyshev metric. It looks that it's pretty difficult task.

Comment: @grom: it should become easier once you know the geometry of the diagram for a line segment or an angle.

Comment: Alas, this task was delayed for an unknown time. So I accepted the David answer. I assume it deserves it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @grom: no worries, I just gave a hint. I know that the complete solution is arduous.